# Specifying the row to use in dv.Table.Rows(x)(VALUE).ToString()

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I have a short page which runs a query and I need to display a specific row based on it's value/content, rather than it's row id (as I do not know what order they will be returned in).

Here's my code, which currently works fine, provided I specify the row id, which in this case is row id 2 (but again, this will be an unknown value so I can not use the row id):

```
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Partial Class test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim strSQL As String = ""
        strSQL &= "SELECT id, item_name, lang_en "
        strSQL &= "FROM language_file_v2 "
        strSQL &= "WHERE item_name = 'SiteLandingPageBodyLoggedIn' OR item_name = 'SiteHomePageMySpecificJobs' OR item_name = 'SiteLandingPageBodyLoggedOut'"

        Using conn As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("customer_support_devConnectionString").ConnectionString)
            Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)

                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                da.Fill(dt)

                Dim dv As DataView = dt.AsDataView()

                LitSiteLandingPageBody.Text = dv.Table.Rows(2)("lang_en").ToString()

            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub

End Class
```

This works, but because I do not know what order the results will be returned in I cannot use Rows(2) as it may not be row 2 that I need.

So instead of dv.Table.Rows(2)("lang_en").ToString() I need a way to specifically display the value in SiteLandingPageBodyLoggedOut (and/or the value returned in 'SiteHomePageMySpecificJobs' for example)
eg.

```
LitSiteLandingPageBody.Text = dv.Table.Rows("SiteLandingPageBodyLoggedOut")("lang_en").ToString()
```

Or eg.

```
LitSiteLandingPageBody.Text = dv.Table.Rows(WHERE("item_name")="SiteLandingPageBodyLoggedOut")("lang_en").ToString()
```

Or similar!

Screen shot attached of how the data looks in the DB.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select function on the datatable to filter the result using the following code

```
Dim drs = dt.Select("item_name = 'SiteLandingPageBodyLoggedOut'")
If drs.Length > 0 Then
    LitSiteLandingPageBody.Text = drs.First()("lang_en").ToString()
End If
```